# Assets folder structure

Tags: ember.js

By default, Ember copies the CSS and (generated) JS files to `dist/assets`.

Would it be possible to add some structure to the assets folder, by copying the JS to `dist/assets/js` and the CSS to `dist/assets/css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the [following part](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#configuring-output-paths) of the ember-cli guides.
Copied here for reference:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var app = new EmberApp({
  outputPaths: {
    app: {
      html: 'index.html',
      css: {
        'app': '/assets/application-name.css'
      },
      js: '/assets/application-name.js'
    },
    vendor: {
      css: '/assets/vendor.css',
      js: '/assets/vendor.js'
    }
  }
});
```

Yours will therefore be something like this:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var app = new EmberApp({
  outputPaths: {
    app: {
      html: 'index.html',
      css: {
        'app': '/assets/css/application-name.css'
      },
      js: '/assets/js/application-name.js'
    },
    vendor: {
      css: '/assets/css/vendor.css',
      js: '/assets/js/vendor.js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I was looking on the wrong guide (ember instead of ember-cli)

Comment: Awesome, innocent mistake :)